# Declaring a global variable in C with .mm and .h files?

Tags: c, global-variables

Hello computing peoples of the world!

I have a bunch of .mm with their respective .h files. I would like one global unsigned int variable that I could use throughout all the source files. Right now I'm trying to do this by placing this statement in one of the .h files:

```
 extern unsigned int global_size_of_instrumental;
```

But I'm getting super strange errors such as:[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put this in **only one** of the **.mm** files:

```
unsigned int global_size_of_instrumental;
```

And then, in every other **.mm** you need to use (reference) it put:

```
extern unsigned int global_size_of_instrumental;
```

Done.

Comment: More likely, put `extern ...` in a header and include it in the `.mm` files.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: yes, you might do that also.

Answer (score 4):

`extern` is an indicator that the variable is defined somewhere *else* rather than "here".

Somewhere (preferably in a C file to avoid the possibility of multiple definitions), you will need just:

```
unsigned int global_size_of_instrumental;
```